# Calling C callback from Ruby using SWIG

Tags: c, ruby, binding, swig

I'm trying to create bindings for a C library to Ruby via SWIG (2.0.3).
Say, we have a function prototype in C that reads:

```
void do_sth_and_call_me_then( (int)(* my_callback)(GlyQuery *, GlyMemCache *))
```

This will do some strange things and eventually calls the callback:

```
int my_callback(GlyQuery * a, GlyMemCache * b)
```

given as paramter several times. As this is the usual way to talk with the library I want to have this behaviour in Ruby too. While researching I found [this](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/128787), which is pretty much what I need:

```
%{
void
wrap_callback(void *user_data, const char *other_data)
{
  VALUE proc = (VALUE)user_data;
  rb_funcall(proc, rb_intern("call"), 1, rb_str_new2(other_data));
}
%}
```

Sadly I can't figure out what I have to change to make this to work with objects other than strings.

If you need more information: the whole interface file is [here](https://github.com/sahib/glyr/blob/master/swig/glyr.i)

Any advice?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a wrapper of callback function, as C library can't call a ruby function directly.

In this wrapper you should convert Structs into something you can pass to ruby code, because ruby can't work directly with C structs.

There is a solutionm which allows ruby code to access C structs, described here
[Wrapping C structs with SWIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700717/wrapping-c-structs-with-swig)

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is to write the wrapper itself. (see also the link above)
I'm unsure on how to represenet my structs in wrap_callback()

Comment: I added link to another question, in which working with structs is described. Can you post details of SomeStruct and OtherStruct ?

Comment: I added a link to the interface file, which is probably the best way to give you all details :-) - also renamed the structs to reflect the reality: 
SomeStruct -> GlyQuery, 
OtherStruct -> GlyMemCache
The link you added did not help much, as the wrapping part works just fine, just the callback is giving me headache.